# Dynamics SSRS Report not selecting current Account in PreFiltered Report

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics, reportbuilder

I have a report which I have built to use the current selected account.

So I have created a Parameter named "CRM_FilteredAccount" and set the default value to:

```
Select * from FilteredAccount
```

Then I create the query like this:

```
declare @sql as nVarchar(max)
set @sql = '
SELECT 
    CRMAF_org.bsv_targetgroupattribute1, 
    pos.bsv_address_multiline, 
    pos.bsv_memberlist_memberlistcode, 
    pos.owneridname, 
    mbl_bsv_memberlist.bsv_memberlistcode, 
    pos.bsv_count_german, 
    pos.bsv_count_french,
    pos.bsv_count_italian,
    pos.bsv_count_rr,
    pos.bsv_count_english
FROM Filteredbsv_memberlist as mbl_bsv_memberlist LEFT JOIN 
Filteredbsv_memberrelation as pos ON pos.bsv_memberlist = mbl_bsv_memberlist.bsv_memberlistid LEFT JOIN 
(' + @CRM_FilteredAccount + ') as CRMAF_org ON CRMAF_org.accountid = pos.bsv_organization'

exec(@sql)
```

To enable the PreFiltering I've set the CRMAV_ Prefix for the FilteredAccount alias and added the parameter to the query like shown above.

The issue is that when I execute the report, still all records are selected instead of the current one on which the report was executed.

So the XML of the Parameter looks like this:

```
<ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="CRM_FilteredAccount">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>Select * from FilteredAccount</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>CRM_FilteredAccount</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
  </ReportParameters>
```

And the dataset:

```
<DataSet Name="AccountData">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>BSV</DataSourceName>
        <QueryParameters>
          <QueryParameter Name="@CRM_FilteredAccount">
            <Value>=Parameters!CRM_FilteredAccount.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
        </QueryParameters>
        <CommandText>declare @sql as nVarchar(max)
set @sql = '
SELECT 
    CRMAF_org.bsv_targetgroupattribute1, 
    pos.bsv_address_multiline, 
    pos.bsv_memberlist_memberlistcode, 
    pos.owneridname, 
    mbl_bsv_memberlist.bsv_memberlistcode, 
    pos.bsv_count_german, 
    pos.bsv_count_french,
    pos.bsv_count_italian,
    pos.bsv_count_rr,
    pos.bsv_count_english
FROM Filteredbsv_memberlist as mbl_bsv_memberlist LEFT JOIN 
Filteredbsv_memberrelation as pos ON pos.bsv_memberlist = mbl_bsv_memberlist.bsv_memberlistid LEFT JOIN 
(' + @CRM_FilteredAccount + ') as CRMAF_org ON CRMAF_org.accountid = pos.bsv_organization'

exec(@sql)</CommandText>
```

Is it possible that this won't work with joins?

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You mean that I have to add the Wehere clause by myself? I thought that this will be added by dynamics implicitly since the prefiltering is enabled by the CRMAF_ prefix

Comment: the dynamic sql part corresponds to the example published by microsoft and there is no where clause. This will be added dynamically by dynamics. This is how I understand the logic.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/analytics/use-parameters-in-reports?view=op-9-1

Comment: Sorry for my misleading comment, the query is valid.

Comment: You have to enable prefiltering for the entity. You can find the information in the same link you mentioned

Comment: @niktrs prefiltering is enabled as soon the relevant entity is aliased with the CRMAV_ prefix which is already done in my query. Or do you mean somewhere else?

Comment: What I dont know is if the CRMAF_ prefix will only be evaluated by dynamics if it is placed right after the FROM in the query. Maybe this construct does not work if the prefilter prefix is part of a join?